# HTML/CSS Including Files For Sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, include

so here is a question that I shouldn't be having so much trouble researching, but I am. Basically I want to create a webpage that loads in a header and a side bar. The header is it's own file header.php and the sidebar is leftBar.php. The following code is my index page, yet I am failing to have these pages loaded. I believe it has something to do with a lacking css page. But I have not found anything useful to help me solve this problem. What I would like to do is have the leftBar.php display its text on the left side of the page and the header.php file at the top. Below is the linked pages.

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>junk</title>
    </head>
    <body>
           junk
    <?php
      include ('styles/header.php');
      include ('styles/leftBar.php');
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

leftBar.php

```
<html>
left
</html>
```

header.php

```
<html>
header
</html>
```

Comment: Now what’s the core problem, do the include file fail to be included at all, or is their content just not displayed where you want it to be? For the first one, check the paths, and for the second one go learn the basics of layouting with CSS.

Comment: invalid html invalid css.

Answer (score 1):

In your include files, just place the code snippet that you want to appear on the page where it's included. You certainly don't want extra `<html>` elements (etc.) included at various places on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup myself for the menu bar of a test site.
I think you have unnecessary brackets around your include file paths.

index.php:

```
<?php
include 'menu.php';
echo "$MENU";
?>
```

menu.php:

```
<?php
$MENU = '<table class="mainmenu"><tr><td><a href="index.php">Home</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href="sites.php">Useful-Sites</a></td></tr></table>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to declare `html` tag for header.php and leftBar.php. A php file should start with `<?php` and end with `?>`. Try learning php first http://w3schools.com/php/default.asp.

Comment: `A php file should start with <?php and end with ?>` Only if you have PHP in it. If it just contains raw HTML to be included elsewhere, the PHP tags are not needed.

Comment: `?>` is optional ad the ens of a file , and in some cases should not be used

Answer (score -1):

trouble researching?

first page of google:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php

http://php.about.com/od/tutorials/ht/template_site.htm

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_inclusion.htm

Please look at these pages, and then update your question if you have to.